# Can I use game name in domain of satiric blog

Tags: copyright, trademark, domain-name

I wanted to start a satiric blog with funny articles, fake level up guides and ranting on updates for a popular French game. Can I register a domain name with the game name and a different TLD without breaking copyright?

For example: https://leagueoflegends.com is the official website for a game

Could I register something like: https://leagueoflegends.online and have my blog hosted there? I know in Europe blogs are protected by freedom of speech however the domain name does contain the game name.

Answer (score 1):

Titles and similar short phrases are not protected by copyright. However, it is likely that "League of legends" is a trademark owned by the same people who own the game. If the intent is to **reference** the game, and if nothing is being sold or advertised, this might count as *nominative fair use*. There is US case law saying that the use of a trade mark in a URL when the site is not conducting any commercial activity is not trademark infringement. But those cases depend specifically on US First Amendment protections, which would not apply under French law  (or in any non-US country), and I am not sure how broadly  French or EU law considers nominative use to extend.